# The series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin(n^4) \sin(4^n)$ converges or not?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Does the series $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin(n^4) \sin(4^n) $$ converges or diverges?

I've been stuck with this problem for a long while and I can't figure out anything. Even I tried to break the $\sin$ into its expansion and still no sign of progress. Really need some help.

Comment: I don't see how this has a solution...what is your interpretation of a trigonometric function??

Comment: $\sin\alpha\sin\beta=\frac12(\cos(\alpha-\beta)-\cos(\alpha+\beta))$

Comment: @KentaS How would that help?  You have the difference of two terms.   Even if each of those associated series diverges, that does not guarantee that the series if the difference also diverges.

Comment: I suspect that this is a Hard Problem and the answer may well not be known. It's _likely_ that the general term doesn't go to zero and thus the series does not converge, but proving that would likely require some very delicate diophantine theory simultaneously bounding $n^4$ and $4^n$ away from multiples of $\pi$.

Comment: @pritam What is the context of this problem?   From where did it originate?

Comment: The answer is known (it diverges), but by the computation time, it seems that [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Convergence+sum+%28sin%28n%5E4%29sin%284%5En%29%29) does not like it

Comment: I'm finding it extremely hard although I tried to use the hint @kenta S gave but no further progress. And also, a first year BSc student gave me this problem so I don't know why it was given in such an early class. And I can't prove that the nth term doesn't converge to 0 either.

Comment: @Mark viola I just answered where it came from.

Comment: I am sure the serie diverge because the term doesn't tend to $0$. You should check and get inspiration from the case of $\sin(n)$ : the limit points of the sequence is the whole $[-1,1]$

Comment: @AlexL And how does one prove that the general term fails to approach $0$?

Comment: @Pritam Consider posting this one on the mathoverflow.

Comment: It may have something to do with Sophie Germain's identity...

Comment: Okay @Mark viola I'll do that